# 11.1 LiPo battery lead got too hot and shows 0 voltage now

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lipo, charging, wire-terminals

I was working on my project using the LiPo battery. I mistakenly connected the battery terminals + to - and - to +, due to which the leads become too hot that it give me a heat shock. The charge in battery returned to zero. I placed it on charge with its charger, but the lights on the charger were not all red to show that it is discharged, one of the three lights was green. I took it out and check it after some time but it wasnt charged. I placed it again , this time 2 lights were green 1 off. I am confused whats wrong. Is the battery out of work? What if I charge it from another battery that is fully charged, connecting it + to + and - to - ?

Answer (score 3):

Please throw away the battery. Do not attempt to charge it with the charger, and please, please, please do not attempt to charge it with another battery. The best case scenario is two dead batteries intstead of one.

If you short circuited plus and minus and they got so hot you got burned you "possibly" exceeded the maximum discharge current (by a factor of 10, possibly), destroying the battery. If you care about it so much you should disconnect the three cells and test them separately and carefully, but they're probably dead.

Search the web on how to dispose of LiPo batteries, there's a somewhat funny procedure you should follow.

Comment: And the worst case involves death and/or dismemberment.

Comment: I bought it on 18$, now i will buy another?

Comment: yeah. I've seen some guys around the net that usually charge fat LiPos in metal ammunition boxes, just in case.

Comment: @BilalAyub - Yes, buy a new battery. $18 is not worth getting blown up over...

Comment: This funny procedure? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-xPHopebiE

Comment: Aaah, venting with flame!  If that were a primary, that vented gas might be HF.  I don't know what LiPos vent.

Comment: you actually need to cut them but they need to be fully discharged.

Comment: If you open up a charged LiPo battery the film inside can still spark and maybe even cause a fire.

Comment: I had to dispose of a battery once: after discharging it I soldered its terminals and let it sit for a couple of days, then cut it. Some people leave them in salty water for weeks to slowly discharge them, then cut them. You can throw them with regular waste but the terminals must be soldered just in case.

Comment: hahah. my question rating is -1 and the answer is 2. what a funny thing.